# Gradle project - can build but not run it

Tags: java, android, gradle

My  Android project consist of 3 `build.gradle` files:

Projects `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
//        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

MYAPP `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/CWAC-AdapterWrapper.jar')
}
```

and Facebook SDK:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0' 
}
```

I am able to build the project but not to run it. The exception is:

```
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
> Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
> use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:unchecked for details. :awakenings:dexDebug UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already
> added: Ledu/mit/mobile/android/imagecache/DiskCache$1;    at
> com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)    at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)     at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)     at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)    at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)   at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)     at
> com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106) UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL
> EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
> Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$1;  at
> com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
>   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)    at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)     at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)     at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)    at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>   at
> com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)   at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)  at
> com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)     at
> com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106) 2 errors; aborting
> Error:Execution failed for task ':awakenings:dexDebug'.
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> non-zero exit value 1
```

Something is duplicated but I don't know what. Have you got any ideas why it does not run?

The problem seems to be that first 2 modules are included TWICE in my DEX

> settings.gradle include ':androidImageCachemaster' include
>   ':facebookSDK'

and then

> ¸¸dependencies {
>       compile project(':facebookSDK')
>       compile project(':androidImageCachemaster')

Here is the screen shot
[image]

Comment: are you making a Library or an App?

Comment: i am building the app , actually importing already made Eclipse project. will try your sample now..

Comment: You need to change your build Gradle to com.android.application.

Comment: did you see my answer? Please choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem was this:
My project included these 2 modules twice:
'androidImageCachemaster' 
'facebookSDK'

after I removed references from the project everything run smooth.

Comment: How is this an answer? I didnt see those dependencies in your `build.gradle` files in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a function called DiskCache in the file:
com.android.dx.command.Main.main

This seems to be conflicting with a function in the facebook sdk. Try to rename your funciton

UPDATED-------

Try this instead in your build.grade. This should compile the dependency but exclude it from the final build:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion x
    buildToolsVersion "x"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'support-v4'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: no its not about function its about project modules. please check my explanation

Comment: For the Facebook build.gradle please try. You are importing the same library twice so you want to exclude it from one place.
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'{
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }

Comment: I am also wonder why you set your compileSdkVersion to be different from your buildToolsVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion now = buildToolsVersion but it does not help. 'exclude group:' option could help but then i cant compile. how can  exclude facebookSDK and androidImageCachemaster so it does not compile twice ?

Answer (score 0):

### Top `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### Facebook for Android:

1. Download the Facebook for Android Gradle library here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android.
2. Import it as a **module** to your own project.
3. It will add it as a module. So add to your own `build.gradle`, `compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1')` as a dependency.

### `app/build.gradle`:

Download the Facebook for Android Gradle library here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' // changed to application

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22 // <-- updated
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" // <-- updated

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11 // <-- updated
        targetSdkVersion 22 // <-- updated
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0' // <-- updated
    compile files('libs/CWAC-AdapterWrapper.jar')
    // compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1') // <-- something like this
}
```